# unable to configure and start nginx

Tags: nginx

my nginx server seemed to run fine but when i do netstat -tupln, I cant see it bound to port 80.

When I fire a http request, it gives me

```
502 Bad Gateway
---
nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
```

Following is the nginx config I have written to both
/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.conf
and /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    location ~ / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }
}
```

I am able to run following commands without any error.
nginx start/stop/restart

but making a http request to the machine gives me following error in /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
08:39:26 [warn] 17294#0: conflicting server name "_" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
08:41:17 [error] 20186#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.123.123.123, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/", host: "123.123.123.123"
```

Even changing the port 8001 to 8003 in mysite.conf files in /etc/nginx/sites-* and restarting nginx doesn't make any difference in above error message which makes me believe that it isn't picking up changes in the conf files.

Can anybody help me understand what is it that i am missing?

Comment: Firstly, you'll want to disable the default conf that comes with nginx (I assume that's causing the name conflict). That being said, the request is hitting your proxy_pass directive. Is there an application serving on port 8001? Are you using Gunicorn or something similar?

Comment: @KeenanLawrence you are absolutely right. luckily, just after posting, I figured out both of them. I didn't expect such a quick reply so many thanks. :) the second one is failing because the gunicorn is unable to start. its unable to find django.http which seems to be a PYTHONPATH issue. working on it

Comment: I'm glad you've figured it out. My suggestion for future projects is to use a virtual environment (`virtualenv` for example) for each application. That way, you won't have issues with paths and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old issue. Would like to put my finding here in case someone encounters the same issue in the future. The way I resolve this issue is by changing `/etc/nginx/` permission.

`sudo chmod -R 777 /etc/nginx/`

Probably more than necessary, but that resolve my problem. Please let me know if anyone find any solid solution